# Comparing combinations of cells in Google sheets / Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm trying to analyse various potential scenarios in Google Sheets.

Firstly, I have a 2 columns of possible prices and sale costs. I would like to combine these into an array of potential profits.

E.g Column A is Cost and B is Sale price. I want a (17x12) array of profits B2:B12-A2:A12.

From there I would like to do the same sort of thing between the array and another 2 columns of variables.

I've tried numerous searches and I expect the answer is out there but I'm not even sure what I should be looking for, so even some pointer search terms would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the significance of `17x12` here? Are there 17 costs and 12 sale prices?

Comment: Yep, exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `Cost` values in the first column and the `Sale price` values in the first row. (Or the other way around - it's up to you.)

[image]

Then, below and to the right, write the formula to evaluate the profits:

[image]

```
=B$1-$A2 (evaluates to 2.00)
```

Then, copy and paste that formula into all the cells under and to the right of the headings:

[image]

The `$`s in `=B$1-$A2` means that, when you paste into a new cell `D5`, the `B` in `B$1` will change to `D` but the `1` will stay a `1`. Likewise `$A2` will become `$A5`. So the formula in `D5` is

```
=D$1-$A5 (evaluates to -4.00)
```

You can safely insert columns and rows above and to the left without breaking those formulas, and prettify the formatting:

[image]

To extend to use more than 2 variables, one approach is to list the extra variables separately:

[image]

Then refer to those variables using absolute references in the formulas:

```
=(C$7-$B8)*$D$3*$D$4
```

[image]

And again copy-paste the formulas across the range:

[image]

Then you can manually adjust the extra values to see their effect on the figures:

[image]

Comment: I maybe should have jumped to the full version of my problem as I'm still confused as where to go from your answer.

I want to evaluate the equation: (Hourly_Price - Cost) * Num_SalesMen * Avg_Num_Hours.

Where there are a number of possible values for each variable.

Comment: That gets trickier - a 2D screen is great for showing 2D data, but now it's 4D. I've updated my answer with one solution.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll try your extra solution but flipped on it's head with the staff and hours in the array and the profit as the manually changeable one